# Let a, b, c $\in \mathbb{Q}$. Prove if $a + c < b + c$, then $a < b$.

Tags: inequality, axioms

I'm lost on how to prove this statement.

Let $a, b, c \in \mathbb{Q}$. Prove if $a + c < b + c$, then $a < b$.

So far, I have

There exists $x_1, x_2, x_3 \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $y_1, y_2, y_3 \in \mathbb{Z}-{0}$ such that $a = x_{1} // y_{1}$, $b = x_{2} // y_{2}$, and $c = x_{3} // y_{3}$.
Suppose $a + c < b + c$. Then, we have

$a + c < b + c \iff (x_1//y_1) + (x_3//y_3) < (x_2//y_2) + (x_3//y_3)$....

How do I proceed next? I don't even know if my idea is correct or not. Thank you.

Comment: Add $-c$ to both sides.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I'm kind of confused. Is it simple like that?

Comment: It depends what you are to prove it from

Comment: I'd guess you have to start from knowing the operation $+$, associative laws, and additive inverses.

Comment: I think I should have specified my question. I have limited properties of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I have associative, commutative, x+0 = 0+x =0, x+(-x)=(-x)+x=0, x(yz)=(xy)z, xy=yx, 1*x=x*1=x,  If x is not 0, then $x*x^{-1}=x^{-1}*x=1$ and distributive.. yikes it looks so bad sorry for my messy comment

Comment: Don't assume the every class introduces the properties of rational numbers in the same way.  *We* have *no* idea how *your* class introduced the properties of $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Q$ so we have *no* idea what basis you are working from and how to do this.  But yes.  Adding $-c$ to each side is *that* simple.... Assuming you have $m < n \implies m + d < n+d$ as an axiom.  Maybe you *don't* and you will have to prove $m< n \implies m+d < n+d$.

Comment: "I have associative, commutative, x+0 = 0+x =0, x+(-x)=(-x)+x=0, x(yz)=(xy)z, xy=yx, 1*x=x*1=x, If x is not 0, then x∗x−1=x−1∗x=1 and distributive."  That's a start.  But what do you have about *in*equalities and order.  What does $a < b$ mean?  Is it possible that $a< b$ and $b < a$ (or that neither is true)?  Do you know that if $a < b$ and $c > 0$ then $ac < bc$? and do you know that if $a<b$ then $a + c < b+c$?  ... The answer probably *is* as simple as adding $-c$ to both sides.

Comment: @fleablood ok it makes sense.. thank you!

Comment: Another theorem you might like to prove will be that if $a < b$ then $-b < -a$. This can also be solved by adding a number to both sides. See if you can puzzle it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your axioms.

You probably have an axiom that if $\alpha < \beta$ then $\alpha + \gamma < \beta + \gamma$ for all $\gamma$.

So you can either prove this by contradiction:

If $a=b$ then $a+c = b+c$ and we know that isn't true; and if $b < a$ then $b+c < a+c$ and we know that isn't true.  So the only option left is $a< b$.

Or we can simply use the $-c$.

$a + c < b+c$ so $(a+c) + (-c) < (b+c)+(-c)$ so $a+0 < b+0$ and $a < b$.

(More thorough details:

$a +c < b+c$ was a given

$-c$ is a number that exists (by definition and existence of additive inverses)

$(a+c) + (-c) < (b+c) + (-c)$ by axiom

$a+(c+(-c)) < b +(c + (-c))$ by associativity

$a+ 0 < b + 0$ by definition of additive inverse

$a < b$ by definition of additive identity.)

.... but ... that's assuming that $a<b \implies a+c < b+c$ is your axiom.  If you introduced you math system by *different* methods, you'd prove this in a different manner.

Answer (score 1):

$a+c < b + c \implies (a+c) + (-c) < (b+c) + (-c) $

$\implies a+(c+(-c) < b+(c+(-c)) \implies a + 0 < b + 0 \implies a < b.$

Since $-c$ is the element $x$ such that $c+x = 0$.